# class component is not defined in Saga-request

Tags: reactjs, redux, saga

I have an Api-request in Saga React. Request function is placed in another folder. I want to call it in Saga file, but get a mistake, that ProductService is not defined. Can it be connected with Saga? The way is right.
The function worked when it was on Saga-page but stopped when I transferred it in another folder.

```
import ProductService from "../services/productService";

function* fetchProductById(productsInList) {      
  ProductService = new ProductService();
  const myListProducts = productsInList.payload.activity.map((item) =>
   //it's request to another file 
  ProductService.getProductByKey(item)
  );
  const res = yield call(() => Promise.all(myListProducts));
  yield put(productsInMyList(res));
}
```

//another folder

```
  export default class ProductService {
        async getProductByKey(key) {    
            const data = new URLSearchParams();
            data.append("key", key);
            const res = await this.getResource(`?${data}`);    
            return await res.json();
          } 
        }
```

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: ReferenceError: ProductService is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of your naming. you have both the imported class and its instance in the same name `ProductService`. You can change your code as below

```
import {call, all} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import ProductService from "../services/productService";

function* fetchProductById(productsInList) {
  const productServiceObj = new ProductService();
  const myListProducts = productsInList.payload.activity.map((item) =>
    call(productServiceObj.getProductByKey, item)
  );
  const res = yield all(myListProducts);
  yield put(productsInMyList(res));
}
```